# Custom View Drawing - Hole inside a View

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

How to draw View like this.

After research I got `context.fillRects` method can be used. But how to find the exact rects for this.

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
context?.setAlpha(0.5)
context?.fill([<#T##rects: [CGRect]##[CGRect]#>])
```

How to achieve this result?

[image]

**Background**: Blue.

**Overlay**(Purple): 50% opacity that contains square hole in the center

Comment: You can use UIBezierpath for this

Comment: What are your constraints? Do you have a precise size for you square and it should be centered? or it should for instance always be at for instance 50 points from the left border and 50 points from the right border, and so on for above and bellow?

Comment: why should I use `UIBezierpath`? is `fillRects:` API not good for this? @RahulDasgupta

Comment: This should be Fully added programatically. Lets say 200x200 box should there as a Hole. Like we are seeing through the Window. @Ocunidee

Comment: OK, working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create your view and then draw everything with two UIBezierPaths: one is describing the inside rect (the hole) and the other one runs along the borders on your screen (externalPath). This way of drawing ensures that the blue rect in the middle is a true hole and not drawn on top of the purple view.

```
let holeWidth: CGFloat = 200

let hollowedView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
hollowedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

//Initialise the layer
let hollowedLayer = CAShapeLayer()

//Draw your two paths and append one to the other
let holePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (view.frame.width - holeWidth) / 2, y: (view.frame.height - holeWidth) / 2), size: CGSize(width: holeWidth, height: holeWidth)))
let externalPath = UIBezierPath(rect: hollowedView.frame).reversing()
holePath.append(externalPath)
holePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

//Assign your path to the path property of your layer
hollowedLayer.path = holePath.cgPath
hollowedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
hollowedLayer.opacity = 0.5


//Add your hollowedLayer to the layer of your hollowedView
hollowedView.layer.addSublayer(hollowedLayer)

view.addSubview(hollowedView)
```

The result looks like this :
[image]

Comment: thanks for your effort. It seems nice. I will check it

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UIView with background color blue.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

// Try adding a rect and fill color.

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

       let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
       ctx!.beginPath()

       //Choose the size based on the size required.
       ctx?.addRect(CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: rect.maxX - 40, height: rect.maxY - 40))

       ctx!.closePath()
       ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
       ctx!.fillPath()

    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not drawing a true hole but just a blue rect on top of a purple one

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up with this.

[image]

Code:

```
createHoleOnView()
let blurView = createBlurEffect(style: style)
self.addSubview(blurView)
```

Method Create Hole:

```
private func createHoleOnView() {

        let maskView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        maskView.clipsToBounds = true;
        maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        func holeRect() -> CGRect {
            var holeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scanViewSize.rawValue.width, height: scanViewSize.rawValue.height)
            let midX = holeRect.midX
            let midY = holeRect.midY
            holeRect.origin.x = maskView.frame.midX - midX
            holeRect.origin.y = maskView.frame.midY - midY
            self.holeRect = holeRect
            return holeRect
        }

        let outerbezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)

        let holePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: holeRect(), cornerRadius: holeCornerRadius)
        outerbezierPath.append(holePath)
        outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let hollowedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        hollowedLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        hollowedLayer.fillColor = outerColor.cgColor
        hollowedLayer.path = outerbezierPath.cgPath

        if self.holeStyle == .none {
            hollowedLayer.opacity = 0.8
        }
        maskView.layer.addSublayer(hollowedLayer)

        switch self.holeStyle {
        case .none:
            self.addSubview(maskView)
            break

        case .blur(_):
            self.mask = maskView;
            break
        }
    }
```

UIView's Extension function for Create Blur:

```
internal func createBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .extraLight) -> UIView {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
    return blurEffectView
}
```